# How to make new apps in iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

So I have my first app ready, and when I try to make my first app iTunes connect asks me for the Company name ( this is ok), but then, when I clik Next, it says:"You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here". What is the Bundel IDs? I'm lost now, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle ID is the unique identifier you give to your iPhone and iPad app when you create it.

E.G. "My Great Application" might have a bundle identifier of "com.user1176834.mygreatapplication.app".

When creating a new iPhone app, here is where you can see the bundle identifier:

[image: bundle identifier graphic]

In Xcode 4.3's case, whatever you type into the "Product Name" field will be copied automatically into the "Bundle Identifier" section; although you can change that later via the Project Settings, if you feel like it needs a change.